# Derived variable creation redshfit

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table of around 3TB on a redshift cluster. As part of some pre-processing step I need to create a few derived variable. The logic for them is very simple, e.g. a variable with difference of two variables etc.

Currently I use a update command to create such variable. The problem with update command is that it bloats the table size and requires a vacuum command to free up space. I am trying to find some way in which I can create such derived variable without the need of vacuum command. I tried creating a different table with the derived variable and joining them on my primary key. But this is equally time consuming as creating the new table and update on it requires almost the same amount of time.

Any other way I can achieve this which is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding you new data in a separate table and joining it should be relatively quick as long as you use `DISTSTYLE KEY` on both tables with the same key and you include the `DISTKEY` in the join between them.